# Wordpress posts_nav_link issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a blog.php with the following code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h1>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
        </h1>
    <section>
        <h3><?php the_category(); ?></h3>
        <h5><?php the_date(); ?></h5>
        <h5><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></h5>
    </section>
    <p class="articlemeta center"></p>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail();} ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php edit_post_link( 'bearbeiten' ); ?>
        <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <h2> 
        Sorry noch keine Texte vorhanden
    </h2>
    <section class="entry-utility">
            <?php $tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', ', ' ); if ( $tags_list ):?>
        <span class="tag-links"> 
            <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Tagged</span> %2$s', 'twentyten' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links', $tags_list ); ?> 
        </span> 
        <span class="meta-sep">|</span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My issue is now, that the  dont compute a navigation. There is also no navigation when i paste the  code at any other destination of the code. I hope anyone could help me to fix my issue.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Need more detail please.

Comment: which details? Everything on the page works, Date, title, content, thumbnail, everything is fine, only the navigation isn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you call `<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>` twice.  I am not sure if this is an error because I don't have much to work with here.

I would take a look at the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link) for guidance.  An example they provide that might help is:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <?php posts_nav_link( ' &#183; ', 'previous page', 'next page' ); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tryed all the codes from the Wordpress Codex, including the one you have written, but nothing works.